# fullPage.js wont destroy on component change

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, fullpage.js

I'm using `@fullpage/angular-fullpage` directive to implement a page scroll feature in my `ionic-Angular` project.

I've created `module` and imported `AngularFullpageModule` to it. I can initialize the plugin as they mentioned in [THIS](https://alvarotrigo.com/angular-fullpage/) documentation. On that module/component its working fine. but when i change the route (which will be in different module) the dots and the functionality of the plugin remains same. it will not destroy on changing the `component`.
I tried to destroy it manually, but when i press back button/come back to old module, the functionality of the lugin is not available anymore.

I recently started working on ionic, i think ionic will not run `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit` on back buttons. (usually with angular I used to run on `ngOnInit`)

On landing page I've initiated, its working fine like below

[image]

but when I change the route/component/module, the functioality remains undestroyed. those 4 dots will be there and on scroll, IDs will be changing on URL bar.

I don't want that functionality on any other page, but on going back to landing page, I need that scroll to be working.

Comment: Could you please share your relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use Ionic's hooks instead of Angular's hooks. Try `IonViewDidLeave()`. https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle#ionic-page-events